# Multiple span tag under one parent DIV id always returns first record

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have multiple span tag with same class name under one parent div id. But, the BeautifulSoup item loop always returns first attribute only, rest of the attributes are not printing.

Note : All of my span class names are same as mentioned below. Any suggestions?

```
<div class="product_constant_fields">
    <div class="width-auto">
        <span class="field_name">Item #:</span>
        <span class="field_value">AB11223344</span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="width-auto">
        <span class="field_name">Brand:</span>
        <span class="field_value">Johns</span>
    </div>

    <div class="width-auto">
        <span class="field_name">UPC#:</span>
        <span class="field_value">12345678901234</span>
    </div>

    <div class="width-auto">
        <span class="field_name">UNSPSC:</span>
        <span class="field_value">12345678</span>
    </div>

    <div class="width-auto">
        <span class="field_name">ManufacturerNo:</span>
        <span class="field_value">1234567</span>
    </div>

    <div class="width-auto">
        <span class="field_name">Alternate MFG #:</span>
        <span class="field_value">87654321</span>
    </div>
</div>

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')

        results = []

        product_attributes = soup.find_all(class_="product_constant_fields")

        for item in product_attributes:
            parsed = {}
            field_name=item.find(class_="field_name")
            parsed["field_name"] = field_name.text
            field_value=item.find(class_="field_value")
            parsed["field_value"] = field_value.text
            results.append(parsed)

        print(results)


**I am getting only first record as output:**

    [{'field_name': 'Item #:', 'field_value': 'AB11223344'}]

**Expected Output:**

    [
    {'field_name': 'Item #:', 'field_value': 'AB11223344'},
    {'field_name': 'Brand:', 'field_value': 'Johns'},
    {'field_name': 'UPC#:', 'field_value': '12345678901234'},
    {'field_name': 'UNSPSC:', 'field_value': '12345678'},
    {'field_name': 'ManufacturerNo:', 'field_value': '1234567'},
    {'field_name': 'Alternate MFG #:', 'field_value': '87654321'}
```

Comment: `<span class="field_valuee">AB11223344</span>` The attribute here is misspelled "field_valuee" instead of "field_value", so I don't see how the code finds that item...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  to change the:

```
product_attributes = soup.find_all(class_="product_constant_fields")
```

to:

```
product_attributes = soup.select(".product_constant_fields .width-auto")
```

Complete code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = '''\
<div class="product_constant_fields">
    <div class="width-auto">
        <span class="field_name">Item #:</span>
        <span class="field_value">AB11223344</span>
    </div>

    <div class="width-auto">
        <span class="field_name">Brand:</span>
        <span class="field_value">Johns</span>
    </div>

    <div class="width-auto">
        <span class="field_name">UPC#:</span>
        <span class="field_value">12345678901234</span>
    </div>

    <div class="width-auto">
        <span class="field_name">UNSPSC:</span>
        <span class="field_value">12345678</span>
    </div>

    <div class="width-auto">
        <span class="field_name">ManufacturerNo:</span>
        <span class="field_value">1234567</span>
    </div>

    <div class="width-auto">
        <span class="field_name">Alternate MFG #:</span>
        <span class="field_value">87654321</span>
    </div>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

product_attributes = soup.select(".product_constant_fields .width-auto")
results = []

for item in product_attributes:
    parsed = {}
    field_name=item.find(class_="field_name")
    parsed["field_name"] = field_name.text
    field_value=item.find(class_="field_value")
    parsed["field_value"] = field_value.text
    results.append(parsed)

print(results)
```

Prints:

```py
[
    {"field_name": "Item #:", "field_value": "AB11223344"},
    {"field_name": "Brand:", "field_value": "Johns"},
    {"field_name": "UPC#:", "field_value": "12345678901234"},
    {"field_name": "UNSPSC:", "field_value": "12345678"},
    {"field_name": "ManufacturerNo:", "field_value": "1234567"},
    {"field_name": "Alternate MFG #:", "field_value": "87654321"},
]
```